# Android input events handling in OS level

Tags: android-hardware

Can some on point how the EventHub.cpp signals the JNI in the later android versions. Before there was a KeyInputQueue.java where all input events were queued. I got the latest android sources and now the KeyInputQueue.java is gone so I am trying to find the JNI/Java class where events are dispatched to android.

Tanks:
T.

Answer (score 2):

The InputManager creates the EventHub and makes one thread for InputReader and one for InputDispatcher.

The InputReader gets the event from EventHub by getEvent() in EventHub. Then, it processes them and sends these cooked events to the InputDispatcherQueue maintained by InputDispatcher.

Then, InputDispatcher dispatches these events to the targets.